# Явный и неявный вид объявление типов в Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Есть явный вид объявления в Swift:
`var test: String = "Hello"`
И есть неявный вид объявления:
`var test2 = "Hi"`
Вопрос: Зачем нам нужен явный вид объявления, когда неявный короче и понятней?

Answer (score 4):

Потому что Свифт не всегда может правильно определить тип данных, например, let x = 1.0 Свифт определит это как Double, а мне может быть нужно Float или что-то другое числовое.

Answer (score 2):

Тип переменных и констант может быть определен *явно* или *неявно*.

1) **Неявный тип**

```
 var personName = "Mike"
```

2) **Явный тип**

```
 var age: Int = 22
```

Однако при таких  подходах(неявных) следует учитывать, что Swift не всегда выводит те типы, которые нам могут быть нужны. Например, все целые числа Swift воспринимает как объекты типа Int, а дробные числа - как объекты типа Double. Это надо учитывать, чтобы не попасть в некорректные ситуации.

Например:

```
var d = 3.4           // тип Double
var f : Float = 1.2
d = f                   // ! Ошибка - разные типы
```

Answer (score 0):

Одно и тоже значение может соответствовать различным классам - например "a" может быть String, Character, NSString, NSMutableString. В таких случаях определенный компилятором тип не обязательно совпадет с вашими ожиданиями, или будет определен неправильно добавляя нам проблем, например 1 может быть определено как  Int, но при прямом указании let double: Double = 1 будет тоже принято. У опционалов и кастомных классов компилятор в принципе не может вычислить тип и его необходимо прямо указывать. Кроме того на автоматическое вычисление типа переменной затрачивается время и ресурсы, что увеличивает время компиляции проекта и может быть значимо в больших проектах.

Comment: Кастомные класы тоже можно присваивать неявно. Также, следует заметить, что во время разработки могут быть случаи, когда нужно объявить базовый класс, а присваивать наследников. Также, можно явно указывать в качестве типа переменной Протоколы, вместо классов.

Answer (score 0):

Бывают такие случаи, когда тип переменной определяется неправильно. Также это помогает в случаях, когда не знаешь, что поместится в эту переменную, ты указываешь тип и ловишь Thread, потому как типы не совпадают. Это очень полезная и интересная функция в Swift.

Также любое дробное значение помещенное в переменную становится типом Double, хотя с целью нормального написания кода, лучше указать Float для экономии места. Об этом сказали выше. Также есть похожие типы данных, но разные -- к примеру с Objc-C пришел такой тип как NSString, но он отличается от простого String, и т.д. Есть множество примеров, где тебе эта функция пригождается.

Ну или как минимум, часто бывают такие случаи в программной разработке, что тебе нужно создать переменную с определенным типом, но ничего туда не помещать, а бывает, что помещаешь какое-либо значение. И было бы странным, что такую возможность не предусмотрели.